# Kotlin Flow: How to unsubscribe/stop

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

**Update Coroutines 1.3.0-RC**

Working version:

```
@FlowPreview
suspend fun streamTest(): Flow<String> = channelFlow {
    listener.onSomeResult { result ->
        if (!isClosedForSend) {
            offer(result)
        }
    }

    awaitClose {
        listener.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```

Also checkout this Medium article by Roman Elizarov: [Callbacks and Kotlin Flows](https://medium.com/@elizarov/callbacks-and-kotlin-flows-2b53aa2525cf)

**Original Question**

I have a Flow emitting multiple Strings:

```
@FlowPreview
suspend fun streamTest(): Flow<String> = flowViaChannel { channel ->
    listener.onSomeResult { result ->
            if (!channel.isClosedForSend) {
                channel.sendBlocking(result)
            }
    }
}
```

After some time I want to unsubscribe from the stream. Currently I do the following:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    beaconService.streamTest().collect {
        Timber.i("stream value $it")
        if(it == "someString")
            // Here the coroutine gets canceled, but streamTest is still executed
            this.cancel() 
    }
}
```

If the coroutine gets canceled, the stream is still executed. There is just no subscriber listening to new values. How can I unsubscribe and stop the `stream` function?

Comment: I think this question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59680533/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-from-coroutines-flow

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It's not exactly the same. My question was how my flow emitter can detect if the flow is no longer needed and it can unsubscribe from a listener.

Comment: There are extension functions which allow you to cancel the scope from within your launch {} block. You should now be able to safely call `cancel()` as you have it in your sample code if you use Kotlin 1.3.7+. See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65121663/1738090

Answer (score 128, accepted):

A solution is not to cancel the flow, but the [`Job`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/) returned from launching the flow in a scope.

```
val job = scope.launch { flow.cancellable().collect { } }
job.cancel()
```

**NOTE:** [`cancellable()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/cancellable.html) will ensure the flow is terminated before new items are emitted to `collect { }` if its job is cancelled, though [`flow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/flow.html) builder and all implementations of [`SharedFlow`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/index.html) are `cancellable()` by default.

Comment: @Farid what is the correct approach?

Comment: @barryalan2633 I have suggested an edit to add `cancellable()` flag after flow and it is approved. Now the answer is correct. I am deleting my previous reply to not cause any further confusion

Comment: in this way the job is not deleted too soon?

Comment: @Farid why Android tutorials doesn't use this `cancellable` method?

Comment: @Ov3r1oad Most of us (including me) copy-paste without actually testing it :). Probably the tutorials you have seen did the same or they didn't need it in that specific context or they were using flow builders which are cancellable by nature

Comment: @Farid, hm, I actually meant official Android tutorials, from the developers site :)

Comment: @Farid I have just test it,  you are right, flow from builders are cancellable by nature

Comment: It’s a bit confusing to say you’re cancelling the scope it’s launched in. You’re just cancelling the coroutine Job.

Comment: It seems cancellable is a hack which is why they are not in android's official documentation or blogs, when the scope that collects the values, or the job which does the collection is cancelled, the flow should collection should be cancelled.

Answer (score 48):

You could use the `takeWhile` operator on Flow.

```
flow.takeWhile { it != "someString" }.collect { emittedValue ->
         //Do stuff until predicate is false  
       }
```

Comment: This solution helped me! The documentation isn't the most obvious but when the predicate in takeWhile{} returns false, the collection completes.

Comment: @n You mean even if the condition changes while collect is being executed?

Answer (score 22):

For those willing to unsubscribe from the Flow within the Coroutine scope itself, this approach worked for me :

```
viewModelScope.launch {

        beaconService.streamTest().collect {

            //Do something then
            this.coroutineContext.job.cancel()

        }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

**There are two ways to do this that are by design from the Kotlin team:**

As @Ronald pointed out in another comment:

**Option 1:** `takeWhile { //predicate }`

Cancel collection when the predicate is false. Final value ***will not be collected.***

```kotlin
flow.takeWhile { value ->
    value != "finalString" 
}.collect { value ->
    //Do stuff, but "finalString" will never hit this
}
```

**Option 2:** `transformWhile { //predicate }`

When predicate is false, collect that value, then cancel

```kotlin
flow.transformWhile { value ->
    emit(value)
    value != "finalString"
}.collect { value ->
    //Do stuff, but "finalString" will be the last value
}
```

https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/2065

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation regarding the difference between these two functions. The `transformWhile` is what I was actually looking for.

Answer (score 5):

With the current version of coroutines / `Flows` (1.2.x) I don't now a good solution. With `onCompletion` you will get informed when the flow stops, but you are then outside of the `streamTest` function and it will be hard to stop listening of new events.

```
beaconService.streamTest().onCompletion {

}.collect {
    ...
}
```

With the next version of coroutines (1.3.x) it will be really easy. The function `flowViaChannel` is deprecated in favor for [`channelFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/channel-flow.html). This function allows you to wait for closing of the flow and do something in this moment, eg. remove listener:

```
channelFlow<String> {
    println("Subscribe to listener")

    awaitClose {
        println("Unsubscribe from listener")
    }
}
```

Comment: I've changed `flowViaChannel` to `channelFlow` and now `isClosedForSend` always returns true. Do I need to specify a channel?

Answer (score 5):

When a flow runs in couroutin scope, you can get a job from it to controls stop subscribe.

```
// Make member variable if you want.
var jobForCancel : Job? = null

// Begin collecting
jobForCancel = viewModelScope.launch {
    beaconService.streamTest().collect {
        Timber.i("stream value $it")
        if(it == "someString")
            // Here the coroutine gets canceled, but streamTest is still executed
            // this.cancel() // Don't
    }
}

// Call whenever to canceled
jobForCancel?.cancel()
```

Answer (score 4):

For completeness, there is a newer version of the accepted answer. Instead of explicitly using the `launch` coroutine builder, we can use the `launchIn` method directly on the flow:

```kotlin
val job = flow.cancellable().launchIn(scope)
job.cancel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ronald answer this works great for testing when you need to make your `Flow` emits again.

```
val flow = MutableStateFlow(initialValue)

flow.take(n).collectIndexed { index, _ ->
    if (index == something) {
        flow.value = update
    }
}

//your assertions
```

We have to know how many emissions in total we expect `n` and then we can use the `index` to know when to update the `Flow` so we can receive more emissions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to cancel only the subscription being inside it, you can do it like this:

```
viewModelScope.launch {
    testScope.collect {
        return@collect cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: so how do you subscribe again

Comment: It doesn't cancel `collect`. It cancels the whole coroutine by calling `CoroutineScope.cancel()`. You are effectively calling `this@launch.cancel()`, hence your `return@collect` does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

`transformWhile` can be used to achieve what you're looking for:

```
@Test
fun test() = runBlocking {
    suspend fun doWork(workFlow: Flow<Int>): Int {
        val timerFlow = flow {
            emit(false)
            delay(3000)
            emit(true)
        }

        var result = 0
        combine(workFlow, timerFlow) { workValue, timeIsUp ->
            Pair(workValue, timeIsUp)
        }.transformWhile {
            emit(it)
            it.first != 100 || !it.second
        }
            .collect { pair ->

            if (pair.second) {
                result = 1
            }

            if (pair.first == 100) {
                result = 100
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    val workResult = doWork(
        flow {
            emit(2)
            delay(1000)
            emit(100)
        }
    )
    assertEquals(100, workResult)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `first` with a **predicate** (i.e. condition)  to stop collecting:

```
myRepository.myDataList.first {
                Timber.d("collected data: $it")
                //condition
                it.size > 0
            }
```

Then it will continue collecting until the condition inside the block is met and then it exits.