# How to cancel/unsubscribe from coroutines Flow

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, kotlinx.coroutines.flow

I notice a strange behavior when trying to prematurely cancel from a Flow. Take a look at the following example.

This is a simple flow that emits integer values

```
  private fun createFlow() = flow {
        repeat(10000) {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
```

Then I call the `createFlow` function using this code

```
  CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
            createFlow().collect {

                Log.i("Main", "$it isActive $isActive")
                if (it == 2) {
                    cancel()
                }
            }
        }
```

This is what is printed out

```
0 isActive true
1 isActive true
2 isActive true
3 isActive false
4 isActive false
etc...etc
```

Now I would expect that the flow should stop emitting integers once it reaches the value of 2 but instead it actually switches the isActive flag to false and keeps emitting without otherwise stopping.

When I add a delay between emissions the flow behaves as I would expect.

```
private fun createFlow() = flow {
    repeat(10000) {
        delay(500) //add a delay
        emit(it)
    }
}
```

This is what is printed out after calling the flow again (which is the expected behaviour).

```
0 isActive true
1 isActive true
2 isActive true
```

What can I do to cancel the flow emission exactly at the specified value without adding delay?

Comment: [This open issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1753) seems to describe the same thing, and I think [this issue](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1657) tracks the progress of this fix.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I came across a workaround in [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1265) related issue

I have replaced every single `collect` with a `safeCollect` function in my project:

```
/**
 * Only proceed with the given action if the coroutine has not been cancelled.
 * Necessary because Flow.collect receives items even after coroutine was cancelled
 * https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1265
 */
suspend inline fun <T> Flow<T>.safeCollect(crossinline action: suspend (T) -> Unit) {
  collect {
    coroutineContext.ensureActive()
    action(it)
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe you can add `.cancellable()` to your `Flow`: 
> This operator provides a shortcut for .onEach { currentCoroutineContext().ensureActive() }.

Answer (score 14):

I want to add that in [1.3.7 version](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/releases/tag/1.3.7) emissions from flow builder now check cancellation status and are properly cancellable. So the code in question will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this recently

it seems that it will only actually cancel if it reaches a suspending point and in your code that emits there is no such point

to solve this either add yield() between emissions or some other suspending function like delay(100)