# Why does Flow (kotlinx.coroutines.flow) not working with Retry even though I manually set as null in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

So basically, on the snackbar action button, I want to Retry API call if user click on Retry.

I have used core MVVM architecture with Flow. I even used Flow between Viewmodel and view as well. Please note that I was already using livedata between view and ViewModel, but now the requirement has been changed and I have to use Flow only. Also I'm not using and shared or state flow, that is not required.

Code:
Fragment:

```
 private fun apiCall() {
    viewModel.fetchUserReviewData()
}

private fun setObservers() {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel.userReviewData?.collect {
            LogUtils.d("Hello it: " + it.code)
            setLoadingState(it.state)
            when (it.status) {
                
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> showErrorSnackBarLayout(-1, it.message, {
// Retry action button logic
                    viewModel.userReviewData = null
                    apiCall()
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Viewmodel:

```
var userReviewData: Flow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>? = emptyFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>()

fun fetchUserReviewData() {
    LogUtils.d("Hello fetchUserReviewData: " + userReviewData)
    userReviewData = flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(true))

        repository.getUserReviewData().collect {
            emit(it)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT in ViewModel:

```
 //  var userReviewData = MutableStateFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>(Resource.loading(false))
var userReviewData = MutableSharedFlow<Resource<ReviewResponse>>()

fun fetchUserReviewData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        userReviewData.emit(Resource.loading(true))
        repository.getUserReviewData().collect {
            userReviewData.emit(it)
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreate() {}
```

}

EDIT in Activity:

```
private fun setObservers() {
    lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
        viewModel.userReviewData.collect {
            setLoadingState(it.state)
            when (it.status) {
                Resource.Status.SUCCESS ->
                    if (it.data != null) {
                        val reviewResponse: ReviewResponse = it.data
                        if (!AppUtils.isNull(reviewResponse)) {
                            setReviewData(reviewResponse.data)
                        }
                    }
                Resource.Status.ERROR -> showErrorSnackBarLayout(it.code, it.message) {
                    viewModel.fetchUserReviewData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I have only single doubt, should I use state one or shared one? I saw Phillip Lackener [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Jc6-INantQ&ab_channel=PhilippLackner) and understood the difference, but still thinking what to use!

The thing is we only support Portrait orientation, but what in future requirement comes? In that case I think I have to use state one so that it can survive configuration changes! Don't know what to do!

Comment: You are trying to reload the data when the state is `Resource.Status.ERROR` but in your `flow` block, I see that you are only emitting the `loading` state & not handling the errors/exception which should emit the `ERROR` state as well.

Comment: @DarShan If you see next line after loading statement in ViewModel, I'm doing actual API call and from  repository.getUserReviewData() this function and also I tried putting other statements log in ViewModel as well, but it is actually not calling!

Comment: @DarShan ^^^ Please check above comment

Comment: Your retry creates a new flow to replace the original, but the Fragment only ever collected the original flow instance. I'm not sure what the point of setting it null is. What do you expect that to achieve?

Comment: @Tenfour04 I was not setting null, but still retry functionality was not working so that's why I tried with null too. My expectation is nothing , but Just I want to do API call again on action button of snackbar using flow.

Comment: This is very difficult to achieve in a clean way without a SharedFlow, because without one, the only way to restart your flow is to create a new one, and then the Fragment has to know when its flow is obsolete so it can cancel the collection coroutine and start a new one to collect the new flow. Very convoluted, and it's the reason your code above is failing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I have figured it out the solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088428/kotlin-flow-how-to-unsubscribe-stop/64785132#64785132] and it is working fine, besaiclly I cancel the current lifecycle coroutine scope and starting again. It is working in that case. You can help me what should I use? Shared flw, Mutable state, stateflow or currently using flow collector, which one is better. My only requirement is to call the API and get the data using flow only and on retry I want to call same API and get data again. Please guide me correctly.

Comment: @DarShan Request you to please read above comment

Comment: You should definitely use a `SharedFlow` backed by a `viewLifecycleOwner` for Lifecycle.

Comment: @DarShan I read definitions but not getting exact diff. Why do you suggest SharedFlow?

Comment: You absolutely shouldn’t cancel the lifecycle scope. I don’t even know how it would be possible to start it up again. Note that the link you just posted says “cancel scope” when they actually meant “cancel job”, so maybe that’s what you did? But it is still a convoluted way to do it. The Fragment should not have to micromanage its coroutines like this to accommodate inner workings of the ViewModel. I’ll have time to post a suggested solution later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the single responsibility principle, the ViewModel alone should be updating its flow to show the latest requested data, rather than having to cancel the ongoing request and resubscribe to a new one from the Fragment side.

Here is one way you could do it. Use a MutableSharedFlow for triggering fetch requests and `flatMapLatest` to restart the downstream flow on a new request.

A Channel could also be used as a trigger, but it's a little more concise with MutableSharedFlow.

```
//In ViewModel
private val fetchRequest = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>(replay = 1, BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)

var userReviewData = fetchRequest.flatMapLatest {
    flow {
        emit(Resource.loading(true))
        emitAll(repository.getUserReviewData())
    }
}.shareIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhlieSubscribed(5000), 1)

fun fetchUserReviewData() {
    LogUtils.d("Hello fetchUserReviewData: " + userReviewData)
    fetchRequest.tryEmit(Unit)
}
```

Your existing Fragment code above should work with this, but you no longer need the ?. null-safe call since the flow is not nullable.

**However,** if the coroutine does anything to views, you should use `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope` instead of just `lifecycleScope`.

Comment: I don't understand why this all required? shareIn(viewMode.... And also why flatMapLatest is required and why try emit? Please see my edited question, that is working fine

Comment: I don't want to collect same value from multiple fragment or activity and fragment. I just want to add retry functionality and obviously, why will I do retry, only when API failed right, so if next time API fail or pass, I'll get emitted value because I manually emitting progress dialog value initially when API starts, so it will happen in retry case also

Comment: Yes, your updated code is better and simpler than mine. Use that. I was thinking of a more complicated use case than what you're doing. Note, even if you only have one Fragment, a SharedFlow prevents it from having to reload from scratch when the user rotates the screen. But with your simpler code, it's already a SharedFlow, so you don't need to use `shareIn`.

Comment: You don't need StateFlow. SharedFlow will survive configuration changes, but you need to give it `replay = 1` in its constructor.

Comment: Hey thanks, I decided to use shared flow only, but why that replay???

Comment: Without replay, if the user rotates the screen, you will have to restart the fetch for it to emit anything.