# Fragment not attached to Activity, How to solve?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using navigation component with bottom navigation view.

**The issue is** When I open the application the selected fragment is home fragment then when I navigate to another fragment(Favorite) and use the context everything is okay. but when I navigate to the home fragment and then navigate to favorite fragment when I use the context the app crashes and I get this illegalStateException : `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Favorite{19d069d} (bfafcdd4-bba2-4005-9437-65c1d0a51977) not attached to Activity`

This is the [behavior](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18F5Qn1o-XYn05464RWkPISVtRfFULqsc/view?usp=sharing)

This is how I initialize the bottom nav with the navController

```kotlin
 val navHostFragment =
            supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.mainFragmentContainer) as NavHostFragment
 navController = navHostFragment.navController

 setupWithNavController(binding.bottomNavigationView, navController)
```

and this is the nav file :

```xml
    <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
    app:startDestination="@id/home">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:name="com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.home.Home"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_menu"
            app:destination="@id/menu" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_home_to_favorite"
            app:destination="@id/favorite"
             />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:name="com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.Favorite"
        android:label="fragment_favorite"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_favorite">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favorite_to_home"
            app:destination="@id/home" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_favorite_to_menu"
            app:destination="@id/menu"

            />
    </fragment>
    </navigation>
```

and the full log :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Favorite{9fbcc19} (f8c928e4-bc35-4543-a26b-f917feb3a9df) not attached to Activity
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1446)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1436)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.Favorite$collectUiEvents$1$1.emit(Favorite.kt:245)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.Favorite$collectUiEvents$1$1.emit(Favorite.kt:235)
at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:37)
at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt.access$emitAllImpl$FlowKt__ChannelsKt(Channels.kt:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.flow.FlowKt__ChannelsKt$emitAllImpl$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:14)
at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:108)
at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:68)
atkotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:375)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.viewmodel.FavoritesViewModel.sendUiEvent(FavoritesViewModel.kt:97)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.viewmodel.FavoritesViewModel.onEvent(FavoritesViewModel.kt:90)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.Favorite$favoriteAdapter$2$1.onWallpaperClick(Favorite.kt:61)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.adapter.FavoriteAdapter.onBindViewHolder$lambda$0(FavoriteAdapter.kt:48)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.adapter.FavoriteAdapter.$r8$lambda$QHKf0dj1K1b9eNHLFJzLaOqv-q0(Unknown Source:0)
at com.androdevelopment.wallpaper.view.favorite.adapter.FavoriteAdapter$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7659)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7636)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30156)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8177)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:552)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:971)
Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b53a2bb, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Comment: well, why use fragment context ?

Comment: your issue probably isn't even fragment context, it's the observers still triggering when the fragment isn't there anymore

Comment: I am using the fragment context for more than one thing for example an Intent, bottom sheet etc....

Comment: And if the issue is the observers how could I stop them when I leave the fragment @a_local_nobody

Comment: `I am using the fragment context for more than one thing for example an Intent, bottom sheet etc....` that doesn't really matter, you could be using activity context or even application context instead. there are [resources available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57088428/kotlin-flow-how-to-unsubscribe-stop) on how to stop an observable

Comment: @a_local_nobody I am using flows so I don't think I should stop them because they stop automatically as per documentation. For the context even if I used the activity context or the application context I get the same exception because the fragment isn't attached to an activity.

Comment: could it be a bug in the navigation component?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the fragment is attached to the activity or not using `isAdded` method.

Simply check it like this and do your stuff:

```
if(isAdded){
    // Fragment is attached.
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this but the user can't navigate to anywhere or make pretty much every thing in the fragment because the fragment isn't attached to the activity thus there is no context

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure that id in Menu should match id in Navigation.**

also try adding or removing (+) in id in menu.

Menu XML:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:id="@id/home"
// some code
/>

<item android:id="@id/favorite"
//some code
/>

</menu>
```

Navigation XML :

```
<navigation
//some code
android:id="@+id/main_navigation"
app:startDestination="@id/home">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/home"
        // some code
/>
</fragment>
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/favorite"
        // some code
/>
    
</navigation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get Activity within fragment and check Activity is null or not

```
 Activity activity = getActivity();
if (!isAdded() && activity == null) {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: I already tried this but this will make the user confused because he can't navigate in the fragment

Comment: It works but `else` what should I do?!

Comment: Do nothing with else, simply check and return, in that case, if fragment not null next line of code will be executed

Comment: I appreciate your solution, but I've encountered an unexpected issue. Implementing it seems to freeze the UI for users, making buttons and other interactive elements unresponsive.

Comment: In that scenario, You need to  fragment back and launch Activity then load the fragment again. If have any other's solution plz share with me

Comment: I just changed back to the fragment manager, and left the navigation components to another time to learn and better understand it :)

Comment: Yeah, Understand